# How can I speed up a transaction for SELECT FOR UPDATE and UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

A few days ago I noticed that multiple workers were fetching the same queue item. I altered my query to avoid this as shown below, but this query is taking a long time (4-5 seconds it varies).

I think the bottleneck is that `queue_items` table has 4 million rows, how can I speed up this query? The only index on the table as of now is the primary key `id`.

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT @id := id
     , item
  FROM queue_items 
 WHERE processed_at IS NULL 
   AND completed_at IS NULL 
   AND confirmed = 1
 ORDER 
    BY id ASC 
 LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE queue_items
   SET processed_at = @processedAt
     , worker_id = @workerId 
 WHERE id = @id;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Why you do not perform this operation in one query? ```UPDATE queue_items SET processed_at = @processedAt, worker_id = @workerId WHERE processed_at IS NULL AND completed_at IS NULL AND confirmed = 1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1```

Comment: HI, as I said in my question the table gets accessed from multiple processes. Using a query as you posted would not be thread-safe and would result in two processes processing the same queue item.

Answer (score -1):

first of all, dont use string concatenation in your programming code. use parameterized queries so that your sql plan wont change and the query is not open to sql injection attacks.

the only thing you can do is to create index in order to speed up `select ... for update` statement

if `Id` is primary key on mysql, It is automatically indexed. You dont need to index it again.

**EDIT: BITMAP indexes are not available on mysql.**

you can create index on columns which is on where clause.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (confirmed, completed_at, processed_at);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! This query was grabbed from a benchmarking utility software I created, production code uses parameters. I think indexes is the way to go, could you elaborate on why you suggested to only index `confirmed` ? I would of thought `INDEX(confirmed, completed_at, processed_at, id)` would be much more effective, no?

Comment: IF they always be used together and you do not have storage concern, your suggested index would work best. I suggested you to create bitmap index because it indexes null values as well

Comment: Could you update your answer to include how I could do this? I am very new to MySQL and SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I will apply this and report back.

Comment: Hi I am receiving an SQL syntax error near Bitmap, could this be because MySQL doesn't support bitmap indexing?